# Spammer on CentOS keeps blacklisting my server

Tags: centos, spam

I am the owner of a server and I have got a spam problem on one of the accounts.

The spammer keeps sending lots of mails from fake non-existing addresses from (only) one of my domains. name@troubledomain.com, anothername@troubledomain.com, yetanother name@troubledomain.com.

Where troubledomain.com is my "trouble" domain.

- CentOS 6.6 final (yum updated)
- Updated all Wordpress installs on the server including all the plugin's
- Changed ftp passwords
- Deleted the whole (spamming) account and created a new one (different
  name)
- Set the max emails to 1

I google'd for days, tried stuff but the IP of the server still gets blacklisted by spamhouse and I get daily emails from DirectAdmin "Warning: 1 emails have just been sent by (USER)".

Part of the mail_queue:

```
ID  Time    Size    Sender  Frozen  Recipient(s)    Select
1Ye8vP-0008OH-0t    0m  2.1K    <>  yes jackie_hancock@troubledomain.com

1Ye8vP-0008OM-6H    0m  1.9K    <>  yes jackie_hancock@troubledomain.com

1Ye8va-0008Ob-UA    0m  746 <randi_workman@troubledomain.com>   no  sadhanaverlag@yahoo.de
```

Part of the Exim_Mainlog

```
2015-04-03 23:51:59 1Ye9VP-0004ur-QI <= <> R=1Ye9VO-0004tD-Jd U=mail P=local S=2120 T="Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender" from <> for vicki_leach@troubledomain.com
2015-04-03 23:51:59 1Ye9VO-0004t2-8N Completed
2015-04-03 23:51:59 1Ye9VP-0004us-QI ** vicki_leach@troubledomain.com F=<> R=virtual_aliases: 
2015-04-03 23:51:59 1Ye9VP-0004us-QI Frozen (delivery error message)
2015-04-03 23:51:59 1Ye9VP-0004ur-QI ** vicki_leach@troubledomain.com F=<> R=virtual_aliases: 
2015-04-03 23:51:59 1Ye9VP-0004ur-QI Frozen (delivery error message)
```

Its really driving me crazy. I thought when i deleted the whole account on DirectAdmin and created a new on, changed all the passwords it would be cleaned, but it started again on the same account.

I installed Maldet and scanned the whole server (sometimes it finds stuff and clean it. This is the last log:

```
TOTAL FILES: 436208 
TOTAL HITS: 2 
TOTAL CLEANED: 1 

CLEANED & RESTORED FILES: 
/maldetect-1.4.2/files/clean/gzbase64.inject.unclassed 

FILE HIT LIST: 
{HEX}gzbase64.inject.unclassed.15 : /maldetect-1.4.2/files/clean/gzbase64.inject.unclassed => /usr/local/maldetect/quarantine/gzbase64.inject.unclassed.19892 
{CAV}Php.Malware.Mailbot-1 : /home/USER/domains/troubledomain.com/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/functions.php => /usr/local/maldetect/quarantine/functions.php.5294
```

Don't really understand why it cleaned 1 of the 2 hits and what to do with them and how to prevent this. If i would do another search tomorrow it will find another file in the Wordpress folder and even if its cleaned spam will still be send.

Again, im not the best administrator there is, but I'm willing / happy to learn..

Note: if you need any information, please tell me how to get it, that way my responses will me much quicker

UPDATE:

I found this when yet another spam session was going on:

```
[root@SERVERNAME virtual]# lsof -i | grep smtp
exim       1503    mail    3u  IPv6   3247      0t0  TCP *:smtp (LISTEN)
exim       1503    mail    4u  IPv4   3248      0t0  TCP *:smtp (LISTEN)
exim      13999    mail    7u  IPv4  39633      0t0  TCP SERVERNAME:40610->mta-v2.mail.vip.gq1.yahoo.com:smtp (ESTABLISHED)
exim      14140    mail    9u  IPv4  40073      0t0  TCP SERVERNAME:56045->mx2.free.fr:smtp (SYN_SENT)
```

Can somebody please share some ideas how to stop this evil stuff?

UPDATE #2

I did some more diggin and found that its sending all the spam from my local machine (from the eximstats mainlog):

```
Top 50 rejected ips by message count
------------------------------------
  Messages   Rejected ip
      1222   local
```

Also when i check the for more highest email usage:

```
Highest         Value                           Count   Percent
Sender          kelli_hogan@troubledomain.com   473     3
Authentication                                  0       0
Sending Host                                    0       0
Sending Script                                  0       0
```

When i check the headers of the one of the spam messages is see this:

```
1YfY3p-0004GS-3R-H
mail 8 12
<>
1428430637 0
-ident mail
-received_protocol local
-body_linecount 29
-max_received_linelength 150
-allow_unqualified_recipient
-allow_unqualified_sender
-frozen 1428430637
-localerror
XX
1
angelia_bass@troubledomain.com
```

Also this message:

> The most common path that the messages were sent from is /, at 15564 emails (7782%).
>   If the path is a system path, it likely means the email was sent through smtp rather than using a script.

Hope this gives more info about the problem and suggestions how to solve this problem that makes me crazy.

Comment: Is your server configured as a open mail relay?

Comment: Web interface panels such as Cpanel, plesk or directadmin are off-topic.

Comment: @andre, I've seen this, but the question isn't about a web interface, i just gave that info, i cant help that people answer web interface related...

Comment: @armani no i just tested it, its not

Comment: Get rid of the offending user.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, true, did that, and found out that the problem is in the theme or plugins. They had added some "viagra" links to some pages using divs with top:-10000; value's in the css.

Stil i need to know how to remove the spammer (and where its send from)

Comment: Wipe your server and start from scratch. Your server appears obviously compromised if I read you correctly and files are being edited on the server directly by unknown actors.

Comment: @gparent Well this was before i updated all CMS install's and plugin's. Now only the mail is beeing send, but i need to know from where. I changed all the logins, only ssh keys to login, no root acces. no accounts have ssh rights.  Its a VPN so i cant start from scratch.. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Directadmin has built in features to ratelimit accounts outbound email by doing the following:

> If you wish to have a custom limit for one or more email address,
>   create a limit in the following path, which will override the
>   /etc/virtual/user_limit file.
>
> echo 100 > /etc/virtual/domain.com/limit/user
>
> where "user" is without the @domain.com.
>   http://www.directadmin.com/features.php?id=1246

If you want to just block the user from sending mail completely, could look for what IP address it is coming from in /var/log/exim_mainlog and then block that with your firewall. Though if this is a legitimate user that you don't want to block, perhaps education and ratelimiting would be better.

To answer the question about how the mail is being sent even if you changed the account passwords, it could be from a script in the website files that wouldn't need to authenticate to send mail. Try to find any offending scripts of this nature.

Comment: Well i know web interface question are off-topic, and i know how to block user emails, but thats the problem, like explained in my initial message, the user always changes. it only should use info@troubledomain.com but it uses like 100xxx different fake non existing users.

As for finding the offending script, any suggestions how to do it. Like i said before i tried it with Maldet, it finds stuff but then a day later there is another threat found..

Comment: Is the troubledomain.com always the same? or does the domain change as well?

Comment: Another way to trace where the emails are coming from would be to go to Admin Level -> Mail Queue Admin in your Directadmin interface. Then if you can see an offending message in the queue, you can look at the full headers to try and trace where it's originating from. See details on this page: http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=455

Comment: Its always the same domain, even deleted the whole account twice (!) and created a new one with a different username. I updated the initial message, please look at the top for more info.

Comment: Since the message is coming from the local machine, it is probably originating from a script on the system. Because it's always from troubledomain.com, this script originates from that user and is probably executed via web. I would look for any scripts in that user's directory that send mail. Common problems would be tell a friend type web pages or malware uploaded (which could be uploaded even though you changed passwords if it comes through an exploit in a web page).

Comment: How can i search for those scripts? I have completely removed the account multible times, installed the CMS again without any themes or plugins. Still spamming. ps. updated an extra log message in the initial message. Thanks again for your quick responses.

Comment: check for suspicious entries in cron directories (/var/spool/cron, /etc/cron*) or in running processes (ps faux). Run a malware scanner.

Comment: could do `grep -Ri mail /path/to/htmldir/` as a start and investigate anything that shows up.

Comment: If you delete this one account and leave it off does the spamming come back? Might be you just need to remove the domain completely

Comment: @HD. No suspicious entries in the /var/spool/cron. What am i looking for in ps faux (that could be suspicious? Maldet in stalled and just ran. Like in my initial post sometimes it finds and cleans stuff but the spamming doesn't stop. When i delete the whole account it also deletes the domain. Can try it again, just need to inform the customer.

@Joe with the `grep` command it finds a lot, like really a lot. For example all the comment templates but also css files etc. Any other ideas that i can try?

Comment: If you can remove the domain for a while to verify that it is in fact coming from that one customer, then I would suggest it. If you find that it is something in that user's stuff, then you weigh the cost of keeping them and being blacklisted vs the cost of removing them. You might consider getting a separate server just to put trouble customers like this one on. Then if that IP gets blacklisted, the only customer affected is the one that caused it.

Comment: @Joe I will talk about this with the customer. I will keep you (all) updated asap.